# Using JNLP as library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, classpath, jnlp

I have a Java desktop application project in Eclipse. I want to integrate a library (JOGL) with some native code into this app. The library provides a JNLP file, which contains the references to the required jar files (also the jars containing the native code for each platform).

I could not believe my eyes that there is no option to use this JNLP file in eclipse as part of the classpath, as a user library or something similar. Did I miss anything? Or what is the preferred way to integrate the contents (and native jars for each platform) of the JNLP file into eclipse?

Comment: i think you can keep it in the runtime working directory of your project in eclipse

Comment: I created the file "libs.jnlp" in the working directory of the eclipse project, which contains the references to the other used .jnlp files, and also tried to add it to the build path, but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, which allows me to load the right native libraries at runtime, so that I do not need a separate launcher or Eclipse runtime configuration for each platform (like windows-i586, windows-amd64, linux-i586, ...).

Unfortunately I can not use the JNLP file, but I can load the appropriate native libs at runtime:

I found some useful piece of code in the org.lwjgl.Sys class of [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org):

```
String osArch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
boolean is64bit = "amd64".equals(osArch) || "x86_64".equals(osArch);
if(is64bit) {
    try {
        doLoadLibrary(lib_name + POSTFIX64BIT);   //does System.loadLibrary(...)
        return;
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        LWJGLUtil.log("Failed to load 64 bit library: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
//load 32 bit lib...
```